# JavaFX Overflow CSS Styling

Tags: javafx-8

I have a simple JavaFX (8) toolbar that is styled by css.
When the screen gets too small the toolbar creates a overflow button that when clicked on creates a dropdown box.
I was wondering what the css style class for that box is?

**EDIT:** The answer is .menu-item and .context-menu

Comment: What always helped me a lot was using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) Maybe it points you to the right direction.

Comment: The problem with ScenicView is the box disappears when the application is not selected so it is not in the list when you alt-tab to ScenicView

Answer (score 0):

Since my toolbar doesn't do this i can't test it but i just looked in scenebuilder and there are 3 possible controls.

It could be menu, menuButton and splitMenuButton. Hope that helps you.